# Using sed to keep the beginning of a line

Tags: sed

I have a file in which some lines start by a >
For these lines, and only these ones, I want to keep the first eleven characters.

How can I do that using sed ?
Or maybe something else is better ?

Thanks !

Muriel

Comment: What about the other lines? Do you want to keep them or discard them?

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with this test file:

```
$ cat file
line one with something or other
>1234567890abc
other line in file
```

To keep only the first 11 characters of lines starting with `>` while keeping all other lines:

```
$ sed -r '/^>/ s/(.{11}).*/\1/' file
line one with something or other
>1234567890
other line in file
```

To keep only the first eleven characters of lines starting with `>` and deleting all other lines:

```
$ sed -rn '/^>/ s/(.{11}).*/\1/p' file
>1234567890
```

The above was tested with GNU sed.  For BSD sed, replace the `-r` option with `-E`.

Explanation:

- `/^>/` is a condition.  It means that the command which follows only applies to lines that start with `>`
- `s/(.{11}).*/\1/` is a substitution command.  It replaces the whole line with just the first eleven characters.
- `-r` turns on extended regular expression format, eliminating the need for some escape characters.
- `-n` turns off automatic printing.  With `-n` in effect, lines are only printed if we explicitly ask them to be printed.  In the second case above, that is done by adding a `p` after the substitute command.

#### Other forms:

```
$ sed -r 's/(>.{10}).*/\1/' file
line one with something or other
>1234567890
other line in file
```

And:

```
$ sed -rn 's/(>.{10}).*/\1/p' file
>1234567890
```